# How do i change the index.html flex output to admin.anotherExtension?

Tags: apache-flex

i need to change the automatically generated index.html flex output to admin.anotherExtension. I understand that if i change the index.template.html the changes in html level will be preserve when the file is generated, however i need to change the name of the file also, and the extension.

Thank you! (using flashBuilder4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html-template directory.  Create a new template file named something like this:

```
${application}${build_suffix}.template.cfm
```

The next time you build your project, you'll get a file with the extension .cfm that is the same name as your application.  You can use whatever extension of your choosing.  [My source](http://www.morearty.com/blog/2006/05/19/customizing-flex-builders-html-templates/)

If you create your own file in the html-template directory (say: index.cfm ), I'm pretty sure that file will be copied to your build directory, but not changed.

Keep in mind all your changes will be overwritten if you change the Flex SDK on the project.  Back them up somewhere.